# Android debugSymbolLevel = { SYMBOL_TABLE | FULL } not working

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to upload an Android app with debug symbols to Google Play Console in order to have detailed crash logs for my C++ code.

So I followed the steps [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#native-crash-support) and added this line:

```
android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'
```

At the top of my Gradle file just below the 'apply plugin:' lines (in the Gradle at :app level)

I also tried to add:

```
ndk {
debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
}
```

in: `buildTypes {  release{ here!!!  }}`

but doesn't work.

I still get the following message in the Google Play Console when I upload my app:

> This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug
> symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes
> and ANRs easier to analyze and debug.

The problem is mentioned [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=debugSymbolLevel) but not solved.

Anybody found a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to upload native debug symbols manually from `app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib` by zipping the content of the folder and uploading it in Google Play Console (View Release Details - click an arrow on app bundle - select Downloads tab - select upload on Native debug symbols). But `debugSymbolLevel` doesn't work for me in build.gradle.kts

Comment: Mike Keskinow answer should be the accepted answer, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case my `build.gradle` script already had a `buildTypes` block and in that block I could set up the `ndk.debugSymbolLevel` config option, an image say more than thousand words, hope it can help you

[image of my build.gradle script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKsov.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).